How to use InputActionPhase?
I'm still trying to figure out the new Input System. I'm trying to implement a pause menu with a time stop in the game.I tried to change the phase check at the button, but nothing gave a positive result.
private bool _onPaused = false;

public  void OnPause(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if(context.phase == InputActionPhase.Canceled)
    {
        if (!_onPaused)
        {
            Paused();
        }
        else
        {
            Resume();
        }
    }
}


And when the pause menu is called. Further attempts to close the pause window are unsuccessful.
Scene and pause menu
private void Paused()
{
    _playerInputActions.Player.Disable();
    _playerInputActions.UI.Enable();
    _menu.SetActive(true);
    _onPaused = true;
    Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
}
private void Resume()
{
    _playerInputActions.UI.Disable();
    _playerInputActions.Player.Enable();
    _menu.SetActive(false);
    _onPaused = false;
    Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
}


After a few days, I came to the conclusion that it is better not to pause the menu after stopping time. I decided to call the pause menu and just turn off the PlayerController so that the attack and movement would not be processed.
private void Paused()
{
    
    _playerController.enabled = false;
    _menu.SetActive(true);
    _onPaused = true;
}
public void Resume()
{
    
    _playerController.enabled = true;
    _menu.SetActive(false);
    _onPaused = false;
}

